# How can I pass Json object to servlet response writer?

Tags: java, json, servlets

I want to pass JSON data to ajax function. But it gives me parsing exception

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".count").on('blur', function(){
        var pack_count = $(this).val();
        var order_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("order?action=update_counter&pack_count=" + pack_count + "&order_id=" + order_id, function(data){
          alert("Change is successfull! Price: ");
          $("#sum").html("Order Price: " + data);
          var price = data['order_sum'];
          var pack_count = data['pack_count'];
          document.getElementById('price').value = price;
          $(this).val(pack_count);
        })
      });
    });
```

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                String jsonData = "{ \"pack_count\" : \"" + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + "\", \"order_sum\" : \"" + countSum() + "\" }";

                out.print(jsonData);
```

### Update:

Solved it! Thanks to [printfmyname](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759845/backslash)

and [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759845/backslash) comments. Just changed jsonData to 
`String jsonData = "{ " +  "\"pack_count\" : " + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + ", \"order_sum\" : " + countSum() + " }";`

Comment: It's confusing: You create a JSON string, convert it to Gson and then print it out as string... Why? Isn't it ok to just print the string?

Comment: I don't quite sure what i need to pass. I just need to get to values in ajax function

Comment: Just try with `out.print(jsonData);` and adjust the content type as @printfmyname states in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wring a json string to output but your header is by default set to text/html or something that is not json. So you need to set proper header before writing to output

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8"); # you may get rid of ; charset=UTF-8 as it is not critical
```

Then when you done writing to output call

```
 out.flush();
```

Update:

You have an error on

```
String jsonData = "{ \"pack_count\" : \"" + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + ", \"order_sum\" : " + countSum() + " }";
```

you a missing a quotation after selectedOrder.getPackageCount() , change to follwong

```
String jsonData = "{ \"pack_count\" : \"" + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + "\", \"order_sum\" : " + countSum() + " }";
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the actual issue? *[...] But it gives me parsing exception*

Comment: This should out put a json object instead of text output, you can not access data['order_sum'] if you send plain taxt. Something else you can do is use $.parseJSON function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ to parse place text in to json data. Also could you copy and paste the reply from the server

Comment: Yes, but again this has nothing to do with the question. JS raises a Syntax Error if the json is malformed or the content type doesn't match, ParseException is happening server-side.

Comment: You have an error on String
jsonData = "{ \"pack_count\" : \"" + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + ", \"order_sum\" : " + countSum() + " }";

you a missing a quotation after selectedOrder.getPackageCount() , change to follwong
String jsonData = "{ \"pack_count\" : \"" + selectedOrder.getPackageCount() + "\", \"order_sum\" : " + countSum() + " }";